# No Viable Alternative to Input '\\n" Python Error

Tags: java, python

I am working on a large scale project that involves giving a python script a first name and getting back a result as to what kind of gender it belongs to. My current program is written in Java and using Jython to interact with a Python script called "sex machine." It works great in most cases and I've tested it with smaller groups of users. However, when I attempt to test it with a large group of users the program gets about halfway in and then gives me the following error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: No viable alternative to input '\\n'", ('<string>', 1, 22, "result = d.get_gender('Christinewazonek'')\n")
```

I am more accustomed to Java and have limited knowledge of Python so at the moment I don't know how to solve this problem. I tried to trim the string that I'm giving the get_gender method but that didn't help any. I am not sure what the numbers 1, 22 even mean.

Like I said since I'm using Jython my code would be the following:

```
static PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();


interp.exec("import sys, os.path");
interp.exec("sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/')");
interp.exec("import sexmachine.detector as gender");

interp.exec("d = gender.Detector()");

interp.exec("result = d.get_gender('"+WordUtils.capitalize(name).trim()
            +"')");

PyObject gendAnswer = interp.get("result");
```

And this is pretty much the extent of Jython/Python interaction in my Java code. If someone sees something that's wrong or not right I would certainly appreciate if you could help me. As this is a large project it takes time to run the whole program again only to run into the same issue, so because of this I really need to fix this problem.

Comment: `"result = d.get_gender('Christinewazonek'')\n")` looks like this line has an extra quote mark

Comment: Even though I manually removed all ' from the file before hand that's weird. But I could try to write something to dynamically look out for extra ' at runtime?

Comment: Why are you writing double slashes? this should work: `/Users/myname/Desktop/`. You only have to escape _backslashes_

Comment: Noted. I would be pretty shocked if that solved the problem.

Comment: I copied the problem name to my smaller subset and I'm experimenting now on how to solve this issue. Definitely a lot better than keeping the name in the large subset.

Comment: Now I'm totally baffled. When I added the problem name to the small group of names the program performed fine with the single / and double // on the file path. That appears not to make a difference.

Comment: I added a Java replaceAll things that are not A-Za-z. I will report back in a couple of hours and see if this works.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago -- but did you find a solution for this? I'm getting a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but this is what I did and it works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    PythonInterpreter pI = new PythonInterpreter();
    pI.exec("x = 3");
    PyObject result = pI.get("x");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you sorted this out, but have an extra apostrophe on

```
d.get_gender('Christinewazonek'')
```

Just like in Java, everything you open you need to close, and in this case you opened a string containing  `)\n")` which was not closed.

Depending on the interpreter you are using, this can be flagged easily. Perhaps you might try different interpreter.